# What are the parameters that one needs to consider while determining the price of an Azure Web Application

Tags: azure

I was thinking of buying Azure Storage for running my Web Service / Application. I went through the Azure Portal and noticed that there are a couple of things I need to buy to make my application completely functional.

The web service should be running on VMs as part of Compute, should have a database storage and also an Azure Storage. On top of that, I have an option to choose whether I want to enable SSL in my website, purchase custom domain URL, enable CDN, global geo-replication among many other options.

I am confused and not sure how should I go about selecting these items.

Can anybody list out the things I would need to setup to get an application up and running on Azure. It would also be helpful if you could point me to the relevant pages / URLs on the same.

Moreover, what are the factors that decide the pricing of these items. e.g. I know that the number of concurrent users decide what scale / pricing tier my compute and storage should be. More the number of concurrent users, the higher should be my pricing tier for Compute and storage.

Comment: why do you want IaaS instead of PaaS?

Comment: More or less Paas.

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic for StackOverflow: This is very broad, and will only get you opinions. There's no right answer to be had here. We don't even know a single thing about your app, performance needs, scale needs, HA/DR needs, etc. This is far too broad and opinion-soliciting. Also, it's not a programming question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @DavidMakogon. I will keep them in mind while posting a question next time. :)

Answer (score -1):

These are the things you should consider buying based on the description of the setup you provided for you application.

1. **Virtual Machine** - provisioning a virtual machine in Azure automatically creates other resources in order for your VM to run properly.

   - The **virtual machine** itself
   - **Network Interface** - serves as the network interface card for you VM
   - **Storage Account** - for storing your VM's hard disk
   - **Public IP Address** - the public address to access your VM, say remote desktop
   - **Virtual Network** - the network where your VM is located, this is where a couple of resources are attached like NSG, NIC, etc.,
   - **Network Security Group** - Azure's firewall for regulating inbound/outbound access to your Virtual Network
2. **Database Storage** - up to you if you want to provision another VM with SQL installed or just provision a SQL database resource. Also you can reuse the Storage Account you have, that's your discretion
3. **SSL** - take a look at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site
4. **custom domain URL** - Azure does provide you a DNS, up to you if you want to use it or not, you have full control of the VM anyway to configure your DNS
5. **global geo-replication** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview

For the pricing, you can always use the pricing calculator: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

But basically, you have to pay for all the resources listed above that are in bold

Comment: Thank you for listing out the steps in so much detail

Comment: this answer is not that helpful, as the person mixed a lot of things together, like sql-georeplication and reusing storage account for Azure SQL. Or a link to buy and use SSL for WebApp (not for a VM)

Comment: Agreed - this is just a collection of *possible* things you can use in Azure. There are *dozens* (or even hundreds) of possibilities. Especially since we don't know a single thing about the app itself.